querying from multiple tables in timescaledb is very slow
Recently we switched to timescaledb for our timeseries data. Basic queries seem to work fine but we have an engine simulator that needs to fetch data from multiple tables, aggregate them and sort them before streaming. However, the below code takes more than a minute which is a problem since we need to stream at least a year's worth of data. Below is my query:
WITH f_md AS (
    SELECT 
        raw_message,
        datetime
    FROM my_f_data
    WHERE
        id=ANY(ARRAY['V03', 'V06'])
    AND
        datetime BETWEEN
        TIMESTAMP '2024-03-20 06:50:00' AND
        TIMESTAMP '2024-03-20 13:00:00'
), s_md AS (
    SELECT
        raw_message,
        datetime
    FROM my_s_data
    WHERE
        id=ANY(ARRAY['S107', 'S057'])
    AND
        datetime BETWEEN
        TIMESTAMP '2024-03-20 10:50:00' AND
        TIMESTAMP '2024-03-20 20:00:00'
), all_data AS (
    SELECT * FROM f_md
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM s_md
)
SELECT * FROM all_data
ORDER BY datetime

The tables are hypertables and timestamp is in microsecond granularity. No primary keys and datetime is the sorting key.
Any suggestion on how to improve this would be much appreciated.

Have you tried creating composite indexes on (id, datetime) for each hypertable?
https://www.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/

@suntruth yes I have. It didn't speed up the query unfortunately.

My guess is that the id=ANY(...) is not optimized.
Can you please, share your explain analyze output of your query?
Also, can you confirm your column in the original hypertable is timestamp and not timestamptz?
Maybe some typecasting inconsistency can be very expensive and not optimize for query chunk exclusion if the data type is different from the hypertable time dimension.
